# Right click menu in IE wont suppress unless I use js alert or when I debug

Tags: internet-explorer, right-click

I'm trying to make a right click menu on a particular type of DIV ... thought i had it working  because when I debug in Visual Studio, the right click menu does not appear.  But when I run it without debugging, the right menu does appear!

If I use an alert() function, this kills the right menu but I do not want to use an alert, I simply want an alternate right click menu to appear and just cant seem to keep the default menu from appearing.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tvance929/5N2ak/

You will notice that if you comment out the alert line - the right click menu will reappear.

I have tried both RETURN FALSE and e.preventdefault() ... Im missing something.

Comment: document.getElementById("note0").oncontextmenu=new Function ("return false");  -- This makes it work.  The jQuery version does not $("#note0") ... Not sure why but at least it's working for me now.
Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tvance929/5N2ak/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer seems to solve the problem only in IE8. In IE5-9 the fix is to use `oncontextmenu` instead of `onkeydown` and in handler:

```
event.cancelBubble=true;
event.returnValue=false;
return false;
```

Comment: My solution above is working in both 8 and 9 for me...but thank you and I will most likely try and end up using yours.